# 41256 / 81256 - dram power and ground confusion

Tags: ground, memory

I'm trying to design a memory board for an Emu Emax sampler to enhance the amount of memory.
Now, when I read the Emax service manual and look at schematics over memory chip connections (in this case the memory type is Fujitsu MB81256-12) the POWER is on pin#16 and GROUND is on pin#8 on memory ic's; but when I read datasheets for the memory chips the signals are swapped (i.e. ground on pin#16 VSS and power on pin#8 VCC). Can it be that it make use of negative voltage compared to ground? What am I'm missing here?

Thank you in advance for any answer(s).

Comment: Believe the datasheet. The schematic was inadequately proofread.

Comment: Link the datasheet in the question. Almost all 16-pin digital ICs of the time had Vdd pin 16 and Vss pin 8. An exception to this would be quite odd ... and highly likely to confuse anyone proofreading schematics as Andy suggests. This one https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/518202/Fujitsu/MB81256-80/1 suggests 81256 IS an exception.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response and thank you for your answers. 
I believe the datasheets are the correct thing to trust, besides I found out that it doesn't matter much when it comes to my memory expansion-card design.
The only thing that matters though is that it is consistent between 81256 and 41256 in case I need to interchange between the two.